# Регулярное выражение для проверки выражения с любым количеством пробелов вначале?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Какой вид будет принимать регулярное выражение для выражения  с любым количеством пробелов вначале
например
"           имимимим имими"
"   fbfbfbf"
должны проходить

Comment: Смысл вашего вопроса не ясен.

Comment: вы можете ознакомиться с краткой справкой по регулярным выражениям в описании нашей метки - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/регулярные-выражения/info

Comment: зачем вообще для обрезки пробелов в начале и конце регулярные выражения?

Comment: В вопросе написано *с любым количеством пробелов*, а принятый ответ находит только строки, начинающиеся с 1 и более пробелов.

Comment: это я сванговал и предположил, что "с любым" не может означать "-1.24 пробела", а имеется ввиду действительные целые числа больше нуля. Если так-то придираться, надо вставить `*` вместо `+`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/^\s+/`

`^` - начало строки
`\s` - пробельный символ
`+` - хотя бы один

Answer (score 0):

Не вижу смысл для обрезки пробелов в начале и конце использовать регулярные выражения.

Для строки используем 
**[trim](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim)**, который, как раз, и удаляет пробельные символы с начала и конца строки. Примеры с тех же доков:

```js
var orig = '   foo  ';
console.log(orig.trim()); // 'foo'

// Другой пример, в котором .trim() убирает пробельные символы только с одной стороны.

var orig = 'foo    ';
console.log(orig.trim()); // 'foo'
```

Comment: Вопрос же не в обрезке, а в матчинге.. если есть такое слово в русском языке. т. е. в логике работы программы, например, необходимо сделать некоторое ветвление логики, основанное на условии, что пробел вначале есть и иная логическая ветвь, если нет.

Comment: @ArcherGodson Приведите пример смысловой нагрузки пробелов в начале и конце строки, желательно в вашем же ответе.

Comment: @ArcherGodson где в вопросе упоминается про матчинг и про ветвление, основанное на условии?